# Spark aggregation with window functions

Tags: pyspark

I have a spark df which I need to use to identify the last active record for each primary key based on a snapshot date. An example of what I have is:

| A | B | C | Snap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2019-12-29 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 2019-12-31 |

where the primary key is formed by fields A and B. I need to create a new field to indicate which register is active (the last snap for each set of rows with the same PK). So I need something like this:

| A | B | C | Snap | activity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2019-12-29 | false |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 2019-12-31 | true |

I have done this by creating an auxiliary df and then joining with the first one to bring back the active indicator but my original df is very big and I need something better in terms of performance. I have been thinking about window functions but I don´t know how I can implement it.

Once I have this I need to create a new field to indicate the end date of the record just filling the field in case that the activity field is equal to false just substracting 1 day to the snap date of the latest date for each set of rows with the same PK. I would need something like this:

| A | B | C | Snap | activity | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2019-12-29 | false | 2019-12-30 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 2019-12-31 | true |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `row_number` ordered by `Snap` in descending order. The 1st row is the last active snap:

```
df.selectExpr(
  '*', 
  'row_number() over (partition by A, B order by Snap desc) = 1 as activity'
).show()

+---+---+---+----------+--------+
|  A|  B|  C|      Snap|activity|
+---+---+---+----------+--------+
|  1|  2|  4|2019-12-31|    true|
|  1|  2|  3|2019-12-29|   false|
+---+---+---+----------+--------+
```

Edit: to get the end date for each group, use `max` window function on `Snap`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.withColumn(
  'activity',
  f.expr('row_number() over (partition by A, B order by Snap desc) = 1')
).withColumn(
  "end",
  f.expr('case when activity then null else max(date_add(to_date(Snap), -1)) over (partition by A, B) end')
).show()

+---+---+---+----------+--------+----------+
|  A|  B|  C|      Snap|activity|       end|
+---+---+---+----------+--------+----------+
|  1|  2|  4|2019-12-31|    true|      null|
|  1|  2|  3|2019-12-29|   false|2019-12-30|
+---+---+---+----------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: and for the second part? How can I pick the snap date for the above record and substract one day?? For substract one day I have tried something like this":
`df = df.withColumn('endDate',when(col("activity") == False, date_add(df['SNAP'], -1)).otherwise(lit("")))` but still don't know how to take the date